# Encoding string to bits in Huffman compression

Tags: java, huffman-code

So I completed my Huffman tree and have accurately found paths to each of the nodes, but they are of type string rather than of a bitString. For example, the path to "e" could be 101 (in type string). Is there a way to simply state that each 1 or 0 is a bit and not of type string?

Comment: You should consider using either BigInteger or BitSet for representing bit strings.  The advantage of BigInteger is that its values are immutable and therefore thread-safe and require no forms of synchronization for mutual exclusion.  BitSet is the mutable companion class to BigInteger and can be used for performance reasons, however for your purpose once the Huffman tree is set, it shouldn't be changed again ... so I would favor the use of BigInteger.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can "just" use BitSet instead of String in your code: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

For more specific hints, you need to provide your source code.